# Parse a tab separated file that contains commas in the fields with awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

I would like to remove all values after ":" in 2nd field of the following input file using awk.

**Input**

```
text1   [a:2,b:1,c:4,k:0]
text2   [d:1,a:5,f:3.2]
```

**Output**

```
text1   a,b,c,k
text2   d,a,f
```

I was able to do this using R but that was kind of slow on larger files.

Comment: What about the `[` and `]`?

Answer (score 7):

Using `sed` (assuming you want to remove brackets too):

```
$ sed 's/\[\|:[^,]*//g' file
text1   a,b,c,k
text2   d,a,f
```

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\[|:[^,]*/,"")}1' file
text1   a,b,c,k
text2   d,a,f
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, thats the logical OR operator. Since `sed` by default supports BRE we had to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
awk '{
  printf "%s ", $1
  n = split($2, a, /[][,:]/)
  sep=""
  for (i=2; i<n; i+=2) {
    printf "%s%s", sep, a[i]
    sep=","
  }
  print ""
}' <<END
text1   [a:2,b:1,c:4,k:0]
text2   [d:1,a:5,f:3.2]
END
```

```
text1 a,b,c,k
text2 d,a,f
```

Comment: It looks like a great implementation... will it be fast enough for a large size flat file? Any comments..?